# How to output columns as conditional functions when creating a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a stored procedure where it returns some selected columns. I'm stumped on how I'm supposed to use conditional functions for the PayComment or TermDate columns. How do I use conditional functions to return columns? I tried looking up any information on adding in conditional statements when creating stored procedures but they all involved using parameter names. Since I was told that this has nothing to do with using parameters, what other method can I use to insert conditional functions to return columns when creating stored procedures?

**PayComment** (use a conditional function so if COLA is yes the phrase “Cost of
living increase appears, if HireDate = StartDate then “Initial Payrate” appears,
otherwise “Pay raise” should appear)

**TermDate** (use a conditional function so if TermDate is null, “Still Employed”
should appear, otherwise the value in TermDate should go here- hint to make
this work you will have to use CONVERT)

My code so far:

```
USE PR;
GO
CREATE PROC spPayIncreaseListing
AS

        IF COLA IS NOT NULL
            PRINT 'Cost of living increase appears.'
            ELSE IF HireDate = StartDate
                PRINT'Initial Payrate'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Pay raise';
        IF TermDate = NULL
            PRINT 'Still Employed'
        ELSE    CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1) AS TermDate;

SELECT FirstName, LastName, CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1) AS HireDate,
PayRate, CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1) AS PayRateStartDate,
CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 1) AS PayRateEndDate
FROM EmpData JOIN TempWork
    ON EmpData.EmpID = TempWork.EmpID
ORDER BY LastName, WorkID;
```

Comment: It looks like your homework... take a look at IIF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but if you are trying to print data based on a value in the column then you can just use

```
SELECT  FirstName, 
        LastName, 
        CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1) AS HireDate,
        PayRate, 
        CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1) AS PayRateStartDate,
        CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1) AS PayRateEndDate,
        CASE 
            WHEN COLA IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 'Cost of living increase appears.'
                ELSE 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN HireDate = StartDate 
                            THEN 'Initial Payrate'
                        ELSE 'Pay Rise' 
                    END 
        END,
        CASE 
            WHEN TermDate IS NULL 
                THEN 'Still Employed'
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 1) 
        END AS TermDate
FROM 
    EmpData 
JOIN 
    TempWork ON EmpData.EmpID = TempWork.EmpID
ORDER BY 
    LastName, WorkID;
```

Comment: Do the double ENDs at the end of the SELECT statement have any function?